# Reference request: Hölder regularity of $(1-\Delta)^{\frac{\alpha}{2}}$ for $\alpha >0$

Tags: reference-request, harmonic-analysis, bessel-potential

Let $j \in \mathbb N$ and $\alpha \in (0, 1)$. We denote by $H^{j + \alpha} := H^{j + \alpha} ({\mathbb R}^d)$ the usual [Hölder space](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder_space). For convenience, we denote $H^{\alpha} := H^{j + \alpha}$ for the case $j = 0$. I have encounter a "classical" result from [this](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0022039623002255) paper.

> **Lemma 5.2.** Let $P_t = e^{t \Delta}$.
>
> 1. For $\alpha \in (0, 1)$, there is a constant $c >0$ such that
>    $$
>    \| (1-\Delta)^{\frac{\alpha}{2}} f\|_\infty \le c \| f \|_{H^{\alpha}},
>    \quad f \in H^{\alpha}.
>    $$
> 2. For $k \ge 0 , j \in \mathbb N$ and $\alpha \in (0, 1)$, there is a constant $c >0$ such that
>    $$
>    \| (1-\Delta)^{-k} P_t f\|_{H^{j + \alpha}} \le c t^{-(\frac{j}{2} - k)^+} \| f \|_{H^{\alpha}},
>    \quad t > 0.
>    $$

Could you elaborate on the references for this result? Thank you so much for your help!